# Problem with the call to method inside the class

Tags: php, class, methods

I'm learning PHP and in this lesson, I'm learning to call a method inside the class. I don't understand the reason why the method that shows the numbers in the cells of my table doesn't show anything. I reviewed it a lot of times but I can find the problem. Could you?

```
<?php 

class Tabla {

    private $row;
    private $column;
    private $mat = array();
    
    public function __construct ($fila, $columna) {
        $this -> row = $fila;
        $this -> column = $columna;
    }




    public function cargar ($fil, $col, $tex) {
        $this -> mat[$fil][$col] = $tex;
    }




    public function mostrar ($fil, $col) {
        echo '<td width="50" height="25">'. $this -> mat[$fil][$col] .'</td>';
    }


    public function graficar () {
        echo '<table border="1">';
        
            echo '<tbody>';
                for($f = 1; $f <= $this -> row; $f++) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for($i = 1; $i <= $this -> column; $i++) {
                        $this -> mostrar($fil, $col);
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';
    }

}

$tablita = new Tabla (3, 3);
$tablita -> cargar(1, 1, "1");
$tablita -> cargar(1, 2, "2");
$tablita -> cargar(1, 3, "3");
$tablita -> cargar(2, 1, "4");
$tablita -> cargar(2, 2, "5");
$tablita -> cargar(2, 3, "6");
$tablita -> cargar(3, 1, "7");
$tablita -> cargar(3, 2, "8");
$tablita -> cargar(3, 3, "9");
$tablita -> graficar ();
```

Comment: Las preguntas y respuestas aquí deben estar escritas en inglés. Por favor utiliza http://es.stackoverflow.com. (Questions and answers here must be written in English. Please use https://es.stackoverflow.com/.)

Comment: Your script prints [a lot of stuff](https://3v4l.org/3q2mW). Can you please be more specific? You may also want to fix the missing variables.

Comment: Sure... @ÁlvaroGonzález my script print a table, and the cells of this table should be a numbers that I introduced in the method "Cargar", how ever this numbers didnt' show in the cells. The html of table print really good, but the number doesn't appear. I reviewed the code, I think the problem is in the call to the method "mostrar", but I can't see any different or bad. Can you see?

Comment: But you're reading from variables that do not even exist. That can't be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my exercise was in the method "graficar" when it use the "mostrar" method... because I setted vars who don't exist, so in this case we should use the vars of the loops for, that represents the rows and columns of the table, that way:

```
public function graficar () {
        echo '<table border="1">';
        
            echo '<tbody>';
                for($f = 1; $f <= $this -> row; $f++) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for($i = 1; $i <= $this -> column; $i++) {
                        $this -> mostrar($f, $i);
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
```